# How to lazy load images?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to find a way to lazy load images on my website, because I'll be having a big gallery of images so I don't want to have any performance issues. I'm following tutorials online where they replace src with data-src but that leaves me with a broken link. Is it possible to do a lazy loading like that if I have a lightgallery integrated?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var lazyloadImages = document.querySelectorAll("img.lazy");
  var lazyloadThrottleTimeout;

  function lazyload() {
    if (lazyloadThrottleTimeout) {
      clearTimeout(lazyloadThrottleTimeout);
    }

    lazyloadThrottleTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
      var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
      lazyloadImages.forEach(function(img) {
        if (img.offsetTop < (window.innerHeight + scrollTop)) {
          img.src = img.dataset.src;
          img.classList.remove('lazy');
        }
      });
      if (lazyloadImages.length == 0) {
        document.removeEventListener("scroll", lazyload);
        window.removeEventListener("resize", lazyload);
        window.removeEventListener("orientationChange", lazyload);
      }
    }, 20);
  }

  document.addEventListener("scroll", lazyload);
  window.addEventListener("resize", lazyload);
  window.addEventListener("orientationChange", lazyload);
});
```

```html
<div class="row gallery-container" id="lightgallery">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 item img-gallery center-images-tattoo image-box" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/tattoo/IMG_1086.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Fading Light</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor doloremque hic excepturi fugit, sunt impedit fuga tempora, ad amet aliquid?</p>">
    <a href="#"><img data-src="images/tattoo/IMG_1086.jpg" alt="Tattoo-image" class="img-fluid img-resize2 lazy"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 item img-gallery center-images-tattoo image-box" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/tattoo/IMG_1089.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Fading Light</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam omnis quaerat molestiae, praesentium. Ipsam, reiciendis. Aut molestiae animi earum laudantium.</p>">
    <a href="#"><img data-src="images/tattoo/IMG_1089.jpg" alt="Tattoo-image" class="img-fluid img-resize2 lazy"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 item img-gallery  center-images-tattoo image-box" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/tattoo/IMG_1090.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Fading Light</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem reiciendis, dolorum illo temporibus culpa eaque dolore rerum quod voluptate doloribus.</p>">
    <a href="#"><img data-src="images/tattoo/IMG_1090.jpg" alt="Tattoo-image" class="img-fluid img-resize2 lazy"></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Which browser do you need to support? Can you maybe use browser implemented `lazy` attribute? https://web.dev/native-lazy-loading/

Comment: I could but I see that it's not supported for safari and firefox.

Comment: It's implemented for Firefox, Safari doesn't support it, that's right. https://caniuse.com/#feat=loading-lazy-attr

Comment: I don't want people on Safari to have worse experience so I'm looking for all-around solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about hiding the non-loaded images from DOM with CSS?

```
img.lazy {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: If I hide them they are still going to be loaded in the background which doesn't really solve it.

Comment: So, basically you want to dynamically add them into DOM.

Comment: Yeah, when a user is approaching to the image it begins to load. I have a gallery at the end of the page so it doesn't make sense to load all images at the beginning. I tried it with the IntersectionObserver but I'm still getting broken link when I change src for data-src

Comment: In order to hide the broken images , I asked you to use the CSS.

Comment: Yes, but then they won't be displayed on a page so the user won't even know they're here

Comment: I assumed that you will remove `data-src` attribute from the element, as you don't need it anymore. Rewriting answer.

Comment: This only works partially. The images disappear completely, but when I'm scrolling in lightgallery, they'll get loaded. Another problem with this method is that I have thumbnails which are also appearing broken, because of the src attribute.